# how to pass the custom transformation parameters to ggplot2::scale_x_continuous

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to transform my data with a customized function `biexp`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = x)) + geom_histogram() + scale_x_continuous(trans = "biexp", myArg = 4)
```

How ever `continuous_scale` doesn't seem to support the customized argument `myArg`

```
Error in continuous_scale(c("x", "xmin", "xmax", "xend", "xintercept"),  : 
unused argument (myArg = 4)
```

Here is the definition of `biexp_trans`

```
biexp_trans <- function(myArg = 4.5){
  trans <- biexp(myArg = myArg)
  inv <- biexp(myArg = myArg, inverse = TRUE)
  trans_new("biexp", transform = trans, inverse = inv)
}
```

Comment: I would expect that the first argument of any transformation would be the vector of values to transform...

Comment: I tried to run your code, but I don't have the `biexp` function loaded. Are you using the one from the `PK` package? Sample data for the graph would also be nice. The way you're defining `biexp_trans` to return a function, you could try calling `trans = biexp_trans(myArg = 4)` in your scale call.

Comment: `biexp` actually constructs a function that does expect the first argument as data values.

Comment: Gregor's last example would be how I'd expect it to work; you pass a `trans` object, and any parameters that you need should be passed in the construction of the `trans` object before passing it on to `scale_x_continuous`, I think.

Comment: `trans = biexp_trans( myArg=4 )`

Comment: Yes, I just figured that out as well. Thanks a lot. `biexp` is also locally defined `biexponential` function.

Answer (score 1):

Two people have pointed out in the comments that the answer is:

calling `trans = biexp_trans(myArg = 4)` in `scale_x_continuous()`